# How to take a dump of a Postgres DB using node js and upload the dump file in s3

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-s3

Is there any a way to dump a Postgres DB using Node JS? How can I upload the dump file into AWS s3 bucket?

Comment: You don't normally dump databases in a programming language - you [use the database vendor tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/backup.html) instead.  Use `pg_dump` and `aws s3 cp` or the node aws sdk to get it to S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can run bunch of `COPY (...) to stdout` commands with [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) [saving the result to the file](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams). Then you can use [aws sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) to put generated files to a bucket.

Apart of it is possible, I suggest you to try using `pg_dump` for backup and `aws cli` for moving it to bucket instead. It can be done with bash one-liner, smth like:

```
pg_dump -d dbname >db.dmp && aws s3 copy db.dmp s3://bucket_name/file_name
```

Comment: thanks for your response.By using copy(...) to stdout commands I'm unable to write the result into a file.It throws the "dest.on is not a function" error.I don't know how to resolve it. anyone guide me to resolve this error.Thanks in advance